# Resolved fetch throws console error 401

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

My `fetch` logs console error, despite of being resolved with `401 Unauthorized`

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ isInitializing: true });
    fetch('/api/users/getcurrent')
        .then(resp => {
            console.log('resolved');
            if (resp.status == 200) {
                // do stuff
            }
            this.setState({ isInitializing: false });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('catched');
            this.setState({ isInitializing: false });
        });
}
```

[image]

Is that the intended behavior of fetch? I do not see anything related to throwing error upon 401 on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) or anywhere else. Console record is a legitimate error. I am not using any pakgages of polyfills for `fetch`. Chrome version is 63.0.3239.108.

Comment: The error comes from the server. It is expected behavior to show the error in the console.

Comment: Chrome displays failed requests in the console. A non-200 or 300 would be considered failed I believe. It looks like `fetch` does *not* reject on failed requests. It's up to you to check the status code. Here's a few of the reasons `fetch` would reject: https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/201#issuecomment-308213104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually has nothing much in common with fetch itself. Chrome Dev tools in default logs HTTP errors (4xx and 5xx status) in console as stated in [Additional settings section here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/). So your fetch promise can be successfully resolved and you only see browser log which can be turned off.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch is working as intended. You got a valid response back from the server it is just that this endpoint is expecting some kind of authorization and sent back a response with a status code of `401`.

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status
>   even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve
>   normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on
>   network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401

Answer (score 0):

Please set your header in your code server.

```
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
 res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because CORS headers are missing from response. I made it to work as expected by adding the following:

```
@Component
public class CORSHeadersToUnauthorizedResponseFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

        if(httpServletResponse.getStatus() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value() ) {

            httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", httpServletRequest.getHeader("origin"));
        }


    }
}
```